# Redownloading gamer profile reset achievements

Tags: xbox-360, assassins-creed-revelations

I've had a Gold Membership for quite some time, but over the last couple months I haven't had internet to connect to.  During that time I've been playing AC: Revelations and got most of the achievements.

So just the other day I got internet again and when I tried to sign in it kept giving me errors and instructed me to redownload my gamer profile.  So now all my achievements are gone for AC: Revelations, but my saved game still works.

Is there anything I can do to get those achievements back?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is unfortunately not. When you redownloaded your profile you overwrote the profile on the console which has the "unlocked achievements" on it.

Some games may unlock achievements again when you load your save, but by the sound of things you've already tried this.